# How to fix 'localhost directed you too many times.' error in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have portal web site and when user login in system. I am checking a Email and Phone Number. If not exist in database. I want to redirect to "ProfilView" page and completed the Email and Phone field. But I got this error "localhost directed you too many times."

This method FilterAttribute and I put over the BaseController

This is my BaseController and I have Attribute

```
[ContactInfo]
public class BaseController : Controller
```

and this is my Attribute

```
public class ContactInfoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute   {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null || filterContext.HttpContext == null || filterContext.HttpContext.Request == null)
                return;

            var workContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
            var customer = workContext.CurrentUser;

            if (customer != null)
            {
                if (customer.PhoneNumber == null || customer.Email == null)
                {

                    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "ProfileView");
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Account");

                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);

                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your redirect leads to a redirect (leads to a redirect (leads to a redirect)) etc... You should only need a single redirect, right?

Comment: Load Chrome. Go to Developer Tools, Network tab. Click `Preserve log`. Load the page. You'll now see the redirects.

Comment: I am going to speculate that `AccountController` inherits from `BaseController` when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is causing recursive redirections. So exclude `ProfileView` action from your redirection logic in filter.

```
 public class ContactInfoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null || filterContext.HttpContext == null || filterContext.HttpContext.Request == null ||
                (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "ProfileView" && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "Account"))
                return;

            var workContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
            var customer = workContext.CurrentUser;

            if (customer != null)
            {
                if (customer.PhoneNumber == null || customer.Email == null)
                {

                    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "ProfileView");
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Account");

                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);

                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```